# HQL Order by query giving problem

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have following query written in HQL for Hibernate.

========================================================================

```
select new map(ret.retailerDesc as ret_name, ret.id.retailerId as ret_id,
               ret.id.serviceId as service_id,  

(select count(distinct i.inspectionId) as inspections from Inspection i 
inner join i.clgCodeStatus c 
inner join c.retailerOrderses r  
inner join r.cusRetailer cr 
inner join i.inspectionMission m  where ret.id = cr.id  ) as inspections ,

(select count(distinct i.inspectionId) as inspections   from Inspection i 
inner join i.clgCodeStatus c 
inner join c.retailerOrderses r 
inner join r.cusRetailer cr 
inner join i.inspectionMission m 
where ret.id = cr.id  and i.inspectionResult = '1'  ) as match,

(select count(distinct i.inspectionId) as inspections   from Inspection i 
inner join i.clgCodeStatus c 
inner join c.retailerOrderses r 
inner join r.cusRetailer cr 
inner join i.inspectionMission m 
where ret.id = cr.id  and i.inspectionResult = '0'  ) as mismatch  )

from CusRetailer ret  order by inspections desc
```

=======================================================================

When above query executes it gives following error:

```
ERROR: column "inspections" does not exist
```

It is giving this error for "order by inspections desc".
If I remove that it works fine.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello,

Can you show the SQL that Hibernate generates for this HQL query (you can make Hibernate print this by setting the show_sql property to true).

From the error it doesn't look like Hibernate is complaining, but your database is.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using "order by col_1_0_" in above query.. because hibernate creates column with names col_0_0_, col_1_0_, col_2_0_ and so on.. so if you just need to know the order of your column and add it to order by accordingly..

Thanks.

amar4kintu

Comment: Are you sure this is a good "solution"? If you add a column to the beginning of the query (or if some other change causes hibernate to re-order columns in some way), your order by is going to point at the wrong column. [This is the same concept that breaks people using ordinal position (e.g. `ORDER BY 1`)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). Surely hibernate in all its glory has a better solution than this hack. I prefer Gareth's proposal if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a case that you need to repeat the expression for `inspections`

```
...from CusRetailer ret order by count(distinct i.inspectionId)
```

It may be that HQL doesn't support expressions in the `order by` clause, you may need to use a n SQL query instead.