# HQL comparison inside the select statement

Tags: sql, select, hql

Consider the following query in HQL:

```
SELECT m.id, (SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) FROM SubqueryTable...) FROM MyTable AS m;
```

I need to return information as boolean from the select query inside the select with information whether there are any entries that satisfy that query.

The above query would work fine translated in SQL, but hibernate gives me an error. I can't use comparison operators with an aggregate function.

What is the proper way to get the information from the subselect inside the select clause, in HQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how this can be transformed into HQL but your query could be written as:

```
SELECT m.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SubqueryTable...) > 0
         AS b
FROM MyTable AS m;
```

But perhaps you could use this - which seems to be bypassing the problem as it is using `INT` columns:

```
SELECT m.id,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SubqueryTable...) > 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS b
FROM MyTable AS m;
```

You could also try with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.id,
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SubqueryTable...) 
         AS b
FROM MyTable AS m;
```

or:

```
SELECT m.id,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SubqueryTable...) 
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS b
FROM MyTable AS m;
```

Comment: The query with exists didn't work for me, but the first one with CASE did. The thought of using case scared me, but it seems it's the only way it works. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with boolean and `BOOLEAN` (which for MySQL means `TINYINT`).

Comment: Or with how MySQL and HQL treat (differently) True/False results/columns.

Comment: See my edit. I guess that queries 2 and 4 work while 1 and 3 do not?

Comment: Now my problem is that I can't order the query by the result of the select inside the case (in your example, by the variable b). My implementation is in HQL, so I'll have to dig a bit on how to achieve that. And the solution I found here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968438/hql-order-by-query-giving-problem doesn't look exactly right to me.

Comment: Whay? Can't you add `ORDER BY b`?

Comment: I get an error smth like Unknown column 'b' in 'order clause' hibernate

Comment: If you do `ORDER BY 2` ? (seeing the answer you link to, it will probably won't work but there is no harm in trying). By the way, `2` means the 2nd column in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: it would work if I do ORDER BY col_1_0_ , cause that's the variable that hibernate generates, but is there any guarantee that i'll get the same name every query?

Comment: I guess that HQL guarantees that. Why there are 2 numbers there, I don't know. Try and dig up some documentation on this.